# Proof: $\sum_{i=1}^pE_i \doteq \bigoplus_{i=1}^p E_i \leftrightarrow \forall i\in \{1,...,p\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,...,p\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})$

Tags: proof-verification

I am using the following definition:

- ***Def.***: let $E_1,...,E_p$ $p$-vector subspaces of $V$, $E_1+E_2+...+E_p$ is direct sum, $E_1+E_2+...+E_p \doteq E_1\oplus E_2 \oplus ... \oplus E_p$, if $$\forall e_1 \in E, e_2 \in E_2,...,e_p \in E_P (e_1+e_2+...+e_p=0_V \to e_1=e_2=...=e_p=0_V)$$

and I must to proof:

- [***Prop.***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690329/about-definition-of-direct-sum-of-p-vector-subspaces): let $E_1,...,E_p$ $p$-vector subspaces of $V$, then:
  $$\sum_{i=1}^pE_i \doteq \bigoplus_{i=1}^p E_i \leftrightarrow \forall i\in \{1,...,p\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,...,p\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})$$
- ***Proof***: I thought (by induction), for $p=2$ I have $E_1,E_2$ $2$-vector subspaces of $V$, and I must to proof $$ E_1+E_2 \doteq E_1 \oplus E_2 \leftrightarrow \forall i \in \{1,2\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,2\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})$$ but $\forall i \in \{1,2\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,2\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})$ means $E_1 \cap E_2=\{0\} \wedge E_2 \cap E_1=\{0\}$ and it is true by [CLIC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690492/proof-by-contradiction-e-1e-2-doteq-e-1-oplus-e-2-leftrightarrow-e-1-cap-e) and because $\cap$ is commutative; I must to proof ($p\to p+1$) $$[\sum_{i=1}^pE_i \doteq \bigoplus_{i=1}^p E_i \leftrightarrow \forall i\in \{1,...,p\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,...,p\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})]\to [\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}E_i \doteq \bigoplus_{i=1}^{p+1} E_i \leftrightarrow \forall i\in \{1,...,p+1\}(E_i \cap \sum_{t \in \{1,...,p+1\}-\{i\}}E_t=\{0\})]$$
  But I don't know to continue, I am confused...mmmm How can I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, induction won't work here.

Comment: @DiffeoR, ah ok.. by contradiction?

Comment: Yes ! that's the way to do. All the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Proof of** $\bf\leftarrow$

Let $e_i\in E_i$ such that
$$e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n=0$$
so forall $i$ we have
$$e_i=-\sum_{j\ne i} e_j\in E_i \cap \sum_{j \in \{1,...,n\}-\{i\}}E_j=\{0\}$$

- **Proof of** $\bf\rightarrow$ *(by contraposition)*

If there's $i$ such that
$$E_i \cap \sum_{j \in \{1,...,n\}-\{i\}}E_j\ne\{0\}$$
so let $x\ne0$ in this intersection hence
$$x=e_i=\sum_{j\ne i} e_j$$
so
$$e_i-\sum_{j\ne i} e_j=0$$
but $$e_i\ne0$$
and this means that $E_1+E_2+...+E_p$ isn't a direct sum.QED.

Comment: Two proofs in one! Nice!